# Angular2. How can I remove empty values when get FormGroup.value using model-driven

Tags: forms, angular

I'm using Angular2 model-driven (ReactiveFormsModule)
I have a form and it have some required and not required fields.
When I submit the main formgroup it generates something like this.
*formgroup.value*

```
{
   "name":"John Doe",
   "birth":{
      "year":1985,
      "month":5,
      "day":17
   },
   "gender":"Masculino",
   "raca":"",
   "cpf":"000.000.000-00",
   "rg":{
      "number":"",
      "orgao":"",
      "uf":""
   },
   "mother":"",
   "father":"",
   "naturalidade":"",
   "addresses":[
      {
         "tipo":"",
         "cep":"",
         "uf":"",
         "logradouro":"",
         "numero":"",
         "complemento":"",
         "bairro":"",
         "localidade":""
      }
   ],
   "cont_telefone":""
}
```

so I need to remove empty "" fields to store on firebase database.

Have angular2 a simple way to handle this or I need to proccess the json by myself?

I have already seen some functions of _lodash like _omitBy, _pick functions but not found a recursively one.

thanks.

Comment: Clarify this "angular2 a simple way to handle this or I need to proccess the json by myself "

Comment: have angular2 a built-in method to get only non empty fields from FormGroup.value ?

Comment: If you disable the fields they don't show up in FormGroup.value, otherwise no.

Comment: Let the consumer (i.e. server-side) logic handle the empty values.